# Need help with memory accounting for non pageable memory

Tags: c, memory-management

I've seen many question regarding the malloc memory consumption, but none of them regarding what I'm dealing with.

I working on a high memory consumption process that's also required good performance.
The code is in C.
My intent is to allow this process to use up to 70% of the machine memory as non-pageable memory (for the performance), and anything above that as pageable memory so the OS will still have some memory to "play" with.

since I need it on run time, any profiling programs (valgrind or similar) are not relevant.

the problem is I can only track the amount of memory I was requesting but not the actual size the malloc is using. so while I'm thinking I have no more than 700Mb allocated the malloc is holding ~1Gb of memory, and since I was asking for non-pageable all that memory is non-pageable and processes are starting to die on me.

If there is a way to know how much non-pageable memory malloc is holding for my process, it will be awesome. But reading the posts here I'm guessing it's still not supported.

I'm open to any idea or advice any one can give me.

Thanks.

Comment: Which platform? You need platform-specific APIs to examine the memory usage of your process.

Comment: you right, sorry for missing to add this info on the post.
I'm working on Linux50 OS, Secure Platform.

Comment: Have a look at /proc/self/status and /proc/self/statm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you need fine control over memory allocation, you should allocate it explicitly with `mmap()` and then provide your own `malloc()` replacement which parcels out your region.  This also saves you from the problem that, if you try to `mlock` stuff in the general `malloc()` pool, you will end up locking more than you intended anyway because the locking granularity is a 4KB page and your locked allocations will be interspersed with general `libc` allocations.

Comment: Thanks,this is probably the approach we are going to use.